# Change directory file in Java (IDE problem)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory, refresh

I have a problem with updating the folders in my IDE during program execution. Basically, during program execution, I allow selecting an image file from the local disk and then copy this image to a folder in my project (folder: Images). The file name will be saved in a database.

When I want to display this image, I retrieve the file name from the database and concatenate it with the path using:
`System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Images\\" + filename`
This gives me an exception because the project folder is not updated until I terminate the program. How can I handle the folder refresh?

Comment: Edit the question - it's hard to help you if you don't show any code or exception information.

Comment: Does it work if you right-click on Images folder and select `Reload from Disk`?

Comment: Does it work if you build/run the project from the command line outside of the IDE? A minimal, reproducible project sample would help to better understand your case

Comment: Not a good idea to attempt that in the first place. Why? Because that's never going to happen with 'real software'. Write to a location that can be used in the real world that doesn't interfere with your dev tree. Try more like `Path imageFile = Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "Images", "foo.jpg");`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

> This gives me an exception because the project folder is not updated until I terminate the program

I doubt that's true. If your program writes a file to a folder (and properly closes the stream), it can then also read the file from the same path. Your IDE updating or not shouldn't factor into it. If you're getting an exception, it's probably caused by something else.

If I had to guess, you are simply reading the wrong path. Is `System.getProperty("user.dir")` resolving to the same path as "a folder in my project (folder: Images)"?

We might be able to help further if you show us the code.